# Java RCaller - basic example not working

Tags: java, r, rcaller

I have R installed here:

C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.2\bin\
Where I find my "Rscript.exe" and "R.exe"

I am using the code sample found [here](http://stdioe.blogspot.com/2011/07/rcaller-20-calling-r-from-java.html)

I have added my rCaller reference for RCaller-2.0.7.jar

When I run the code
1 - I cannot have just the path above, I need to put the full path and file name (.exe). If i do this I get:

```
        run:
        [Fatal Error] Routput5525030595700249151:1:1: Premature end of file.
        packageExist<-require(Runiversal)
        if(!packageExist){
        install.packages("Runiversal", repos=" http://cran.r-project.org")
        }

        packageExist<-require(Runiversal)
        if(!packageExist){
        install.packages("Runiversal", repos=" http://cran.r-project.org")
        }

        x<-c(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0);
        y<-c(2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0, 10.0, 12.0, 14.0, 16.0, 18.0, 30.0);
        ols<-lm(y~x)
        cat(makexml(obj=ols, name="ols"), file="C:/DOCUME~1/Jason/LOCALS~1/Temp/Routput5525030595700249151")

        rcaller.exception.RCallerExecutionException: Can not handle R results due to : rcaller.exception.RCallerParseException: Can not parse the R output: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/DOCUME~1/Jason/LOCALS~1/Temp/Routput5525030595700249151; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
        BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Now..I am not a pro in R but if i go in and try to `install.packages("Runiversal",repos="http://cran.r-project.org")` i am told:

> install.packages("Runiversal", repos=" http://cran.r-project.org")
>   Warning: unable to access index for repository  http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib
>   Warning: unable to access index for repository  http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/2.15
>   Warning message:
>   package ‘Runiversal’ is not available (for R version 2.15.2)

Please I am sorry about this post but I cannot think of a better way to demonstrate my issue/frustration.

Thank you.

Comment: the error is misleading. after a little digging on the website of the project i found that you only need to run: install.packages("Runiversal")

Comment: If you solved it, then you should accept your own answer.

Comment: @jasonm what is your option default repos options , type e.g `options()$repos`?

Comment: was not an option to save at the time. i figured it out too quickly.